# Camera transformation, how to distinguish object in the front and the back?

Tags: graphics, camera, camera-calibration

I have a camera transformation matrix `K * Rt` where K is the intrinsic and Rt is extrinsic, which maps a 4-dimensional homogeneous coordinate X to pixel coordinate on the image Y.

```
Y = K*Rt*X
```

This works fine and it does map the real-world points to my image. However, for some reason, it is also mapping some points that should not be inside the image into the image, so I wonder if these points are from the back of the camera.

So my question is, where will the point from the back of the camera be mapped to if we apply this transformation to them?  And if it will also be mapped to the image within the same pixel, how can we distinguish if it's from the back or front of the camera?

Answer (score -2):

Think what is "Rt*X". Then

> how can we distinguish if it's from the back or front of the camera?

is obvious.

> where will the point from the back of the camera be mapped to if we apply this transformation to them?

is obvious too.

Just confirm (calculate `K*Xc`, where `Xc` is the "back of the camera" position) by yourself if needed.

Comment: There is a transformation equation. Question is "Where will the point mapped to". If want to know it, just calculate the equation. This is "obvious". Is this wrong? What is wrong?

Comment: the question is more like why is the points at the back of the camera mapped into the image according to camera transformation, and how to protect it.

Comment: e.g. for a equation f(x) = x*x, all x is "transformed" to positive value.
Your question is like that "why negative x value also transformed to positive value?".
The reason is obvious : becasuse you are using such equation.

Comment: And as already said in this answer, if you see the position of points in the camera-coordinate system, "front or back" is obvious (generally, just see the z value).

Comment: So, now, I can't understand what is your unclear point. All thing seems as "obvious".
If you think this answer is not for your question, please represent about your real problem more explicitly.